# Free site to show code development bogs/webpages?

Tags: gratis, hosted, blog

I am looking for a free site on which I can create a blog or articles by my own (like WordPress or Tumblr), but on which it is easy to create a page with mixed content, like text, code and images. I am looking for a free site on which I can:

- Create single sites and sub-sites
- On each page I can insert text (with some syntax highlighting), images, code snippets...
- On which visitors can give a feedback

I want to be able to create a page like [this one](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm) (the middle column).

Comment: The site you link to says in its faq it is based on wordpress. Why dont you want to use [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

## `gh-pages` [link](https://pages.github.com/)

If you want total control, i.e. the html file served then use `gh-pages`. These are ideal for projects, blogs and pure html. For this you might need a understanding of git etc.

everything you make with `gh-pages` is available for every one. Your source code will be on the repo. Also, gh-pages is not ideal for dynamic pages. Only static html.

I have created a little bit of pages using it, you vcan visit them here :

- http://arcxon.github.io/todx
- http://adilnx.tk // My blog, you may be interested in this
- http://adiultra.cf
- http://adiultra.github.io/noteworthyhtml
- http://adiultra.github.io/esencia // You may like something like this